# Format time for China with my HTML clock (-9 hours) while maintaining non military time?

Tags: javascript, html

See 6th line of my code where I do getHours and -9 hours. I am in CA and want to get the time in China. The problem is when I get into the early hours china time i get a - (for example: -1:54 AM). How can I modify the code to prevent this? Note I want to keep 12 hour time format so as to avoid the time showing this - sign.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
function displayClock() {
var digital = new Date();
var hours = digital.getHours()-9;
var minutes = digital.getMinutes();
var seconds = digital.getSeconds();
var amOrPm = 'AM';
if (hours > 11) amOrPm = 'PM';
if (hours > 12) hours = hours - 12;
if (hours == 0) hours = 12;
if (minutes <= 9) minutes = '0' + minutes;
if (seconds <= 9) seconds = '0' + seconds;
dispTime = '<b>'+hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' ' + amOrPm+'</b>';
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = dispTime;
setTimeout('displayClock()', 1000);
}
</script>
</head>

<font color="gray">
<span style="font-size: 12pt">

<body style='font size:24; face:Arial;background-color:rgb(255,255,255);margin-left: 0px;margin-top: 0px;margin-right: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;text-align:left; border:0; margin:0; padding:0' onload='displayClock()'>
<div id='time'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that you whole parsing can be condensed to `digital.toLocaleString('en-US', {hour12: true, hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'})`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
var hours = digital.getHours()-9;
```

you can let the date arithmetic do it for you:

```
digital.setHours(digital.getHours()-9);
var hours = digital.getHours();
```